# How to prevent a column from repeating in the final result when using the LISTAGG function

Tags: oracle, query-performance, oracle-11g-r2

I have a table like this:

```
CUST_NUMBER | CUST_NAME | CUST_PROFESSION
------------------------------------------  
   1        |   Mike    |    Teacher
   1        |   Mike    |    Engineer
   2        |   Jack    |    Driver
   3        |   Charlie |    Swimmer
   4        |   Negin   |    Engineer
   5        |   Zahara  |    Manager
```

In want to use the `LISTAGG` function to produce this result:

```
  CUST_NUMBER | NAME_PROFESSION
  -----------------------------
       1      | [Mike:Teacher,Engineer]
       2      | [Jack:Driver]
       3      | [Charlie:Swimmer]
       4      | [Negin:Engineer]
       5      | [Zahara:Manager]
```

What I've written so far is the query below:

```
select cust_number,
       '['||listagg(cust_name||':'||cust_profession,',')  within group (order by cust_number)||']' Cust_profession 
from CUSTOMER_PROFESSION 
group by cust_number;
```

The problem I have is that this gives me `[Mike:Engineer,Mike:Teacher]` (as you can see , the name Mike is repeated) instead of `[Mike:Teacher,Engineer]` . How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Extended answer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to see employee name out of aggregated professions list - so you must concatenate it to aggregating expression, not to separate profession in arguments.

If do this directly

```
select cust_number,
       '['||MAX(cust_name)||':'||listagg(cust_profession,',')  within group (order by cust_number)||']' Cust_profession 
from CUSTOMER_PROFESSION 
group by cust_number;
```

then `cust_name` become non-grouped, and Oracle produces an error "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression".

This can be solved either by wrapping this column with aggregated function, for example, MAX():

```
select cust_number,
       '['||MAX(cust_name)||':'||listagg(cust_profession,',')  within group (order by cust_number)||']' Cust_profession 
from CUSTOMER_PROFESSION 
group by cust_number;
```

or by adding this column into grouping expression (preferred):

```
select cust_number,
       '['||cust_name||':'||listagg(cust_profession,',')  within group (order by cust_number)||']' Cust_profession 
from CUSTOMER_PROFESSION 
group by cust_number, cust_name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fbb3046e66459e777aa9ce83eebc2a88)